# Can't upload image via Channel Forms

Tags: safecracker, permissions

I have a channel form set up [here](http://mobilearts.org/calendar/submit-event) where non-registered users can submit upcoming event information. The form works fine except when you try to upload an image. It generates an error message about file upload permissions.

In the file upload permissions area there isn't an option to allow uploads for non-registered users. Is there a way to allow for this?

Here is the code for the form.

```
{exp:channel:form channel="calendar_events" class="artist" return="calendar/confirmation"}


<p><label for="title"><span>*Name of Event</span>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" size="50" maxlength="100" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();">
</label>
</p>

<p><label for="submitting_organization"><span>*Organization</span>
<input type="text" name="submitting_organization" id="submitting_organization" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
</label>
</p>

<p><label for="submitted_by"><span>*Contact - Full Name</span>
<input type="text" name="submitted_by" id="submitted_by" value="" size="50" maxlength="100">
</label>
</p>


<p><label for="contact_phone"><span>*Contact - Phone Number</span>
<input type="text" name="contact_phone" id="contact_phone" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
</label>
</p>


<p><label for="submitters_email"><span>*Contact - Email</span>
<input type="text" name="submitters_email" id="submitters_email" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
</label>
</p>

<p><span>*Date and Time</span>
{exp:calendar:date_widget}
</p>

<p><label for="event_location"><span>*Event Location</span>
<input type="text" name="event_location" id="event_location" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
</label>
</p>

<p><label for="event_address"><span>*Event Address</span>
<input type="text" name="event_address" id="event_address" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
</label>
</p>

<label for="event_summary"><span>*Description of Event</span></label>
<textarea name="event_summary" rows="5" cols="65" >{event_summary}</textarea>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<br />
<span>Photo (optional)</span>
{field:event_thumbnail}
<br />

<p><label for="admission"><span>*Cost of Admission</span>
<input type="text" name="admission" id="admission" value="" maxlength="75" size="50">
</label>
</p>

<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of some possible ways to do this; but why bother when my Google-fu is mighty? Found this:

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/logmein

And although that page hasn't been updated in a while, the last comment is from May this year giving it five stars. I would give that a try before planning some sort of hack. But it looks like it's just what you need, the example on that page even hints at doing exactly what you want:

```
{exp:logmein:now username="priveleged_guest"}
```

So you create a "Privledge Guest" member group, restrict it to nothing but file uploading to your guest uploads folder, and put that tag on your form page. Voilà!